# How can I drag sortable element into an other sortables elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have 2 lists of sortables elements and I need to be able to drag an item from list to an other list:

I have tried to do it but it seems that it doesn't work correctly.

My code:

```
<div class="sortableCard"> 
    <div   class="draggable">car 5</div>
    <div   class="draggable">car 6</div> 
</div>

<div class="sortableCard"> 
    <div  class="draggable">car 1</div>
    <div class="draggable">car 2</div>
    <div class="draggable">car 3</div>
</div>

$(function() {
    $(".sortableCard").sortable({
        revert: true
    });

    $(".draggable").draggable({
        connectToSortable:'.sortableCard',
        revert: "invalid"
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MxrrZ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists

```
$( ".sortableCard" ).sortable({
  connectWith: ".sortableCard"
}).disableSelection();
```

Comment: Thanks, that's working !! but one thing, when a list become empty we no longer can drag into it, I have tried to add "dropOnEmpty: true" but it doesn't work , how can we fix that ?

Comment: dropOnEmpty is true by default.  Your problem is you have no physical space to drop onto.  Add a padding to the sortableCard class and then you have something when all the divs are gone from it.
http://jsfiddle.net/Wr56n/

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the list like this and then you will be drag any items from top list to the bottom one.

```
<body>
    <div class="sortableCard1">
        <div class="draggable">car 5</div>
        <div class="draggable">car 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sortableCard2" style="padding-top:40px">
        <div class="">car 1</div>
        <div class="">car 2</div>
        <div class="">car 3</div>
    </div>
</body>

 $(function () {
     $(".sortableCard1").sortable({
         revert: true
     });

      $(".sortableCard2").sortable({
         revert: true
     });

     $(".draggable").draggable({
         connectToSortable: '.sortableCard2',
         revert: "invalid"
     });
 });
```